Binding Properties for a dynamic list
I have the below original query which need to be refactored to prevent KQL injection.
let apps= dynamic(["a", "a.b.c"]);
MainTable
| where Day == datetime(2024-06-20) and Region == "region"
| where (Component contains "a") or (Component contains "a" and Component contains "b" and Component contains "c")
| summarize sum(TotalBytes) * 1.0 / 24 / 60 / 60

I have a function which appends the where condition string to the above query:

 var appNameFilter = string.Join(" or ", appNames.Select(name => ParseAppNames(name)));

 private static string getAppNameParts(string app)
    {
        var splited = app.Split('.');
        return " ( " + string.Join(" and ", splited.Select(name => $"Component contains \"{name}\"")) + " ) ";
    }

I want to use ClientRequestProperties to bind parameters to the KQL query. How can I do this with a dynamic list of apps?
I tried modifying the query but running into memory constraints : has_all(): failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant

Is this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78780924/how-to-match-multiple-values-in-a-list-of-lists

This question is similar to: How to match multiple values in a list of lists?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
