How to match multiple values in a list of lists?
I have a list of items and I need to split each of the items by a delimiter to convert that to a list.
let apps = ['a', 'a.b.c']
...
SummaryTable
| where column has(apps)

Note:
If all the parts of an item from the dynamic list are present in the column then it is match. (I need to compare it with all the items in the list)

If the column has a - It is a match.
If the column has a,b and c - It is a match.
If the column has b - It is not a match.


To match the list of lists, you can try the below approach. I have taken sample data for summarytable and apps.
//sample data for summary table
let summarytable= datatable ( column:string )
[
'a b c',
'd e',
'a e d',
'b c'
];
//apps data 
let apps = print names = dynamic(["a.b.c","a"])
| mvexpand names
| project parts = split(names, "."), Placeholder = 1;
summarytable
| extend Placeholder = 1
| join kind=inner apps on Placeholder
| extend parts_copy = tostring(parts)
| mv-expand parts
| extend parts=tostring(parts)
| extend check=iif(column has(parts),1,0)
| summarize  min_check= min(check) by column, parts_copy
| summarize final_check= max(min_check) by column
| project column, available=iif((final_check==1) ,'match','not-match')

Output:
The output for the sample input data taken,



column
available




b c
not-match


a e d
match


d e
not-match


a b c
match



demo
